# Electric field due to charge in one direction

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I am supposed to calculate the electric field due to the charge density $\rho(x) = Ax e^{-\lambda |x|},$ where the density is supposed to be homogenous in $y,z$ direction.

The problem is, that the integral $$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 } \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \rho(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}} dxdydz $$ does not converge. What am I missing here?

Comment: This seems nonsensical. Assuming $A,\lambda>0$, you have $\underset{x\rightarrow-\infty}{\text{lim}}\rho(x)=-\infty$, which is unphysical. So there must be something wrong with the question itself.

Comment: not anymore ;-)

Comment: Computing the potential and then finding $\nabla\phi$ is probably going to be difficult, and there might be weird convergence problems (but I'm not sure). However, the problem becomes much easier when you consider Gaussian surfaces. Make a cylinder pointing in the $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ direction, with one circular face located at $x=-\infty$, and the other face located at $x=X$. Then note that the field vanishes at infinity.

Comment: Why would you expect this integral to converge?